# One post carries 30 postmeta values, is this too much?

Tags: database, post-meta, performance

I have some data saved as post meta, occasionally some plugins may save an extra piece. Now I installed bbpress, it saves at least 10 pieces of post meta. Adding them together, there are nearly 35 pieces of post meta per post. I think WordPress can handle much more if without bbpress.

**With bbpress forum, the number of posts will increase dramatically, multiply by the number of post meta, it will be a huge post meta table**. Will it be a problem?

Comment: That depends more on server performance than WordPress itself...

Comment: so, if not want moving to new server at a future stage, better reduce postmeta per post at the very beginning, right?

Comment: try saving serialized data where possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, to be honest 35 is nothing. You should not see any problems scaling this into the hundreds/thousands if optimized right, it does depend on many factors.

Where is the post meta being used, are you sure it's all being used?

Are you using a lot of unique keys? You can check this by doing `get_post_custom_keys`, the lower the better.

Are you outputting all post meta in one shot using `get_post_custom` instead of getting each field via `get_post_meta` ?

You should always turn on debugging with `define('SAVEQUERIES', true);` and see how many hits to the DB your doing and how long each one is taking.

Comment: All data I created are used frequently, votes, flags...and so on. Not sure about bbpress. As for the unique key, I tried get_post_custom_keys, all bbpress custom keys not showing up, they all start with "_", I know that makes it hidden from UI, you mean, it also have other benefits?

Comment: No that's it, "_" hides it. Just look at the debug output it should tell you what you need to know in terms of the speed of a query.